# Chaining clauses in a pattern match, how to add missing bindings

Tags: ocaml

I have a type defined as such:

```
type quantity = Value of int | Direction of int * int | Vector of int * int * int
```

Later I have functions that operate on values of the latter two subtypes together:

```
match q with
| Direction(x, y)
| Vector(x, y, magnitude) ->
```

Is there some way of defining magnitude to be 0 if the first pattern is matched? I know that I can use `let x, y, magnitude = match (...)` to convert the type into a tuple, or combine Vector and Direction into one subtype, setting magnitude to 0 where appropriate.
But I am looking for something concise.

Comment: Also.. Please note, that piece of code should have generated a warning `match non exhaustive`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot bind add bindings to patterns
( `match q with Direction(x,y) and m = 0 ->` in fantasy syntax). However, in this case it seems as simple to define a magnitude function

```ml
let magnitude = function
  | Direction _ | Value _-> 0 
  | Vector (_,_,m) -> m
```

and then use it:

```ml
match q with
| Direction(x, y)
| Vector(x, y, _) ->
  let magnitude = magnitude q in
  ...
```

On the other hand, more often than note the need to generate magical values from variant is a sign that your type definition does not fit the underlying concept.

For instance, why is the magnitude of a direction 0? Why do vectors have magnitude as a component? If the first two arguments of the vector variant are in fact a direction, why is that not apparent in the type?

Comment: I agree that the type could probably be improved. The example I used in my question was simplified for brevity. The quality of an ontology is subjective. The parameter I am using to measure it here is the amount of code I have to write to process values of the type. It's true that Direction could be made explicit in Vector. But then I need an extra match in functions that only accept Directions. Another fantasy syntax here would be:

```let rotate (restrict Direction (x, y)) =
  (* Didn't have to deal with magnitude *)```

Comment: Certainly, quality is subjective, and that part of my answer was here to mention that type design and code design are often coupled in OCaml (or any language with algebraic types really). Often defining the "natural" type simplifies the writing of the "natural" code (for some value of "natural") .

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure that I understand your question. If the first pattern matches then quantity is of the direction subtype, so there is no vector. So depending on what you're asking it could be something like this,

```
match q with
| Direction (x,y)
| Vector (x,y,0) ->
```

which will match with either a direction or a vector that has zero magnitude.

Alternatively, if by "defining a magnitude to be 0" you mean creating a vector with zero magnitude to which a direction should be mapped, then it could be done as,

```
match q with
| Direction (x,y) -> Vector (x,y,0)
```